# CentOS 8 - uninstalled python, How to recover laptop?

Tags: linux, centos, python, centos8, crash

Yes I know I'm an idiot, I just need help

I have a laptop running centOS 8 and I was trying to set another default version of Python. Long story short I used
`sudo dnf remove python` and my laptop immediately crashed and now when I boot it just brings me to a command line. What are the steps I can take to safely recover?

```
#rpm -q centos-release
>centos-release-8.2-2.2004.0.2.el8.x84_64
```

Since booting just brings me into a command line now, I ran  `dnf install python3` hoping to get functionality back but when I restart it continues to boot like this, anything else I can do?

Comment: What exactly do you see on the screen now?

Comment: It just boots to a command line that asks me login info, when I enter it I'm just left in CLI and have use the command line.

Comment: A normal command line? Or something else?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to answer, immediately after logging in when I run 

```# ls 
> anaconda-ks.cfg initial-setup-ks.cfg
```

I can ```cd /``` and be in the root directory and see ```bin, boot, dev, usr```, etc. I can run commands like yum (even though I don't think it can actually work now?) and others

Comment: I tried to just dnf install python again to see if it would get everything working but it did not unfortunately. Not sure if that was a dumb move.

Answer (score 0):

You could revert the last transaction with:

```
dnf history undo last
```

Since you already ran something else, reverting last won't restore to the desired state.
List the last 5 transactions:

```
dnf history list | head -n5
```

Then *rollback* to the one *prior* to the ID that corresponds to when you mistakenly deleted Python, e.g.:

```
dnf history rollback 123
```

The `123` should be a transaction that was *before* you deleted Python, aka "last good transaction".